# Subsetting data with the subset() function using logical operators

Tags: r

I'm using the subset function quite a bit but I'm constantly having an issue where, if I want to subset data based on multiple factor levels I end up with non-subset data.

I'm well aware of working around that by creating a list and subsetting it manually using the %in% method, but it just seems counter-intuitive that I can't do it in the following way:

```
#sample data 
Code <- c("A","B","C","D","C","D","A","A") 
Value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4) 
data <- data.frame(cbind(Code, Value))
```

So, assuming I'd like to get only rows containing codes A and B:

```
data = subset(data, Code != "C" | Code != "D")
```

This results in nothing happening!
It just seems to me there should be a clean way of doing this by using the subset() function. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need `subset(data, !Code %in% c('C', 'D'))`. FYI `subset` is not `dplyr`. Just good ol' base R

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still kind of surprised that the method I showed above doesn't work for the function. Alas. This does certainly do the trick.

Comment: Also. Thanks for the clarification about dplyr. I just assumed.

Comment: You need `&` for your method to work, not or (`|`), i.e. try `subset(data, Code != "C" & Code != "D")`

Comment: Right! This is what I was looking for. Seemingly I'm misunderstanding the logical operators.